# Spring Webapplistener Issue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, listener

I seem to be having some trouble with Spring webapplistener. I'm deploying an open-source servlet which I did not develop myself.

I'm a little new to the tomcat platform, so any thoughts as to potential fixes would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
May 30, 2013 12:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    May 30, 2013 12:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener
    java.lang.Error: Failed to load configuration
        at org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:78)
        ... 14 more

    May 30, 2013 12:01:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    May 30, 2013 12:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'fetchArticleService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: ERROR: Configuration not loaded or initialized.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1654)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    May 30, 2013 12:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    May 30, 2013 12:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    May 30, 2013 12:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    May 30, 2013 12:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5c845ce9')
    May 30, 2013 12:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    May 30, 2013 12:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener
    java.lang.Error: Failed to load configuration
        at org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:78)
        ... 30 more

    May 30, 2013 12:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    May 30, 2013 12:02:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'fetchArticleService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: ERROR: Configuration not loaded or initialized.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    May 30, 2013 12:02:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    May 30, 2013 12:03:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
    May 30, 2013 12:03:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

Answer (score 0):

When we look at the error stack trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'fetchArticleService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: ERROR: Configuration not loaded or initialized.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
```

you notice the following error:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'fetchArticleService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Check if your bean definitions are properly defined.  The following example shows the basic structure of XML-based configuration metadata:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="..." class="...">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
  </bean>

  <bean id="..." class="...">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
  </bean>

  <!-- more bean definitions go here -->

</beans>
```

Check with Spring Docs to make sure you have the bean definition in the applicationContext.xml right.

Comment: <bean id="fetchArticleService" class="org.ambraproject.service.article.FetchArticleServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
    <property name="articleTransformService" ref="articleTransformService" />
    <property name="fileStoreService" ref="fileStoreService" />
    <property name="articleHtmlCache" ref="articleHtmlCache" />
    <property name="pubGetLookupService" ref="pubGetLookupService"/>
    <property name="guestCrossRefUrl" value="${ambra.services.crossref.guestquery.url}"/>
  </bean>

Comment: I see that there is `Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c`. Try putting the actual url and see if the bean accepts it. If it accepts it, then its the url variable that is causing the problem.